# Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-errors, fold

The task I want to handle is described as below:

> `pipe [f1,...,fn] x` should return `f1(f2(...(fn x)))`

Here is my code:

```
pipe :: [(a -> a)] -> (a -> a)
pipe fs   = foldl' f base fs
  where
    f a x = a (x)
    base  = (\x -> x)
```

I think this makes sense as it iterates through the function list, however, the compiler tells me:

```
tutorial.hs:45:20: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ a -> a
      Expected type: (a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
      Actual type: ((a -> a) -> a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
    • In the first argument of ‘foldl'’, namely ‘f’
      In the expression: foldl' f base fs
      In an equation for ‘pipe’:
         pipe fs
            = foldl' f base fs
            where
                f a x = a (x)
                base = (\ x -> x)
    • Relevant bindings include
        fs :: [a -> a] (bound at tutorial.hs:45:6)
        pipe :: [a -> a] -> a -> a (bound at tutorial.hs:45:1)
   |
45 | pipe fs   = foldl' f base fs
   |                    ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I am a newcomer to Haskell, and Thanks for your help in advance:)

Comment: `pipe = appEndo . foldMap Endo`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342013/the-composition-of-functions-in-a-list-of-functions

Comment: `pipe fs x = foldr f x fs` with the same `f` as you have. it can also be written as `f a x = a x = a $ x = ($) a x` so we can just write `($)` instead of `f` in the definition of `pipe`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
pipe :: [a -> a] -> (a -> a)
pipe = foldr (flip (.)) id
```

There is a difference between `foldr` and `foldl`.

Your `base` function is equivalent to `id`.

In your version, the definition of `f` is incorrect. It should take two functions and return a new function.

You could write it as

```
pipe :: [(a -> a)] -> (a -> a)
pipe fs   = foldl f id fs
  where
    f g h = g . h
    base  = (\x -> x)
```

or

```
pipe :: [(a -> a)] -> (a -> a)
pipe fs   = foldl f id fs
  where
    f g h a = h (g a)
    base  = (\x -> x)
```

If all functions are commutative, using `foldr` or `foldl` makes no difference, otherwise you need to choose `foldr` or `foldl` correctly.

Comment: But I still wonder why this will give me a infinite type error, is it because I pass in function as parameter?

Comment: the 1st and 3rd definitions are the same, and both are wrong. interestingly, both `foldr (.) id` and `foldl (.) id` produce the same result, because `(.)` is associative and `id` is `(.)`'s zero (IOW `(.)` and `id` form a monoid, which is the basis of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52564838/occurs-check-cannot-construct-the-infinite-type#comment92068067_52564838) by Daniel Wagner). Using `flip (.)` instead again produces *the same result* with *both* `foldr` and `foldl`, the result being the *reversed* composition of the list of functions.

Comment: (+1) and (*2) are not commutative. `take 1` and `drop 1` are not commutative. not many functions are, and it goes to the choice between `(.)` and `flip (.)`, not between left and right fold.

Comment: I think both foldr vs foldl and flip (.) vs (.) matters in this case: (foldr (flip (.)) id) [(/2), (+1)] 10 == 6.0, (foldl  (.) id) [(/2), (+1)] 10 == 5.5.  (foldr (flip (.)) id) should be the correct solution in this case

Comment: no, they *both* are correct, with foldr and foldl alike. just try *all four* combinations and see the results. flip (.) gives *reversed* composition. `foldr (.) id [f,g] = foldl (.) id [f,g] = f . g`, `foldr (flip (.)) id [f,g] = foldl (flip (.)) id [f,g] = g . f`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain why your code is not working. Let's compute `pipe [g,h] x`. We expect this to be `g(h x)`.

I will ignore the types, and simply compute according to the definitions:

```
pipe [g,h] x
= foldl' f base [g,h] x
= foldl' f (f base g) [h] x
= foldl' f (f (f base g) h) [] x
= f (f base g) h x
= (f base g) h x
= base g h x
= g h x
```

So, in the last line we can see that `g` is called with two arguments, `h` and `x`, while we expected to have `g (h x)` instead.

The mistake is that `f` uses application `f a x = a x` instead of composition `f a x = a . x`. Using the latter we would get

```
... 
= ((base . g) . h) x
= base (g (h x))
= g (h x)
```